# paypal buy button return the customer details

Tags: paypal

I am trying to do a mobile shopping cart and wish to make the process as simple as possible.

The client selects the products and I calculate the totals.

He clicks buy now and the total is sent to paypal express.

The product details are stored in our own database.

We need to only allow delivery to paypal account holder address and only verified accounts

I don't want the client to have to enter his delivery address (as it is stored at paypal).

So how can I ease the pain and get the customer details.

I am redirecting back to a page on the mobile when site when completed. Can I pass the data when this happens?

I am using a buy now button:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" id="business" value="payment@xxxx.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"  value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="12.99">
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://xxxx.com?pageToJump=pagePayPalCompleted" />  <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://xxxx.com?pageToJump=pagePayPalCancelled" /> 
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

MrWarby.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Buy Now button this information is not passed back by default, you would need to enable PaymentDataTransfer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/ or InstantPaymentNotification https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: How do I do this using a buy now button.?

Comment: Thanks. I am going dow the PDT route.